# Absolute position in td on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, css, browser, css-position

My phone is on Android 2.3.3 and it uses the stock browser (HTC Desire aka. Bravo).

I have a table and it has many rows. One row has two cells.

I have set the position of second cell as `relative`, and in this cell, I have a `div` that's position is `absolute`. My purpose is to show a text on right top side of each cell. On my desktop computer on Firefox 37, everything is great, but on Android, it shows that text on right top of the whole page, and not each cell. So, it absolute positions the text according to page not each cell.

Is this a known issue? and is there any fix for this? (Note: Position value is `absolute`, not `fixed`.)

td.info:

```
position: relative;
padding: 8px 8px;
vertical-align: top;
border-bottom: solid 1px #f0f0f0;
```

.category:

```
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
text-align: right;
font-size: 70%;
color: silver;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Instead of setting `position` of `td` element, I created a `div` as the first element of `td`, and set its `position: relative`. Then put the category into that new `div` element. Now it works as expected.